# swift - auto connect hotspot

Tags: ios, swift, hotspot, nehotspothelper

I know it has been asked before but I am asking again to make sure I didn't miss anything. I am currently using the next code in order to connect a specific hotspot. This prompt a message to the user -

```
     let configuration = NEHotspotConfiguration(ssid: ssid,
                                                   passphrase: password,
                                                   isWEP: false)
      NEHotspotConfigurationManager.shared.apply(configuration)
```

Is there anyway I can connect automatically without prompting this message? I need to switch between hotspots every few minutes. I don't mind showing the message once and after that connecting automatically but is there any way I can do it?